# Is it possible to use "bad" data returned from a jsonp call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a jsonp call to another domain that gets data, but it's just json, not wrapped in a function. So, it errors out with a parserror. But, the data is there - I can see it.

Is it possible, even with this error, to use the data that came back? Basically, can I get the error-laden data into a variable somehow?

Basic call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: api_url,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error: " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

Error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Inspecting the error (in chrome) shows valid json, but not jsonp...

Comment: JSONP only works if the server supports it.  If the server does not, see if it supports CORS.  If not, then you can't use the data.  A workaround would be to use a proxy on your webserver.

Comment: Also, why are you setting the `jsonpCallback` parameter?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I was setting basically every parameter trying to see what happened. Forgot to remove that for the question. As for the first comment, I figured as much. It's just that I can see the data! It's right there! And I want it!

Comment: JSONP works by adding a `<script>` tag to your page header.  That's how it bypasses the same-origin policy.  JSONP is not JSON, it's just a JavaScript file; a function call.  If it's not wrapped in a function call, it's not JSONP, and cannot be used.  Your only option if the server doesn't support JSONP (or CORS) is a proxy.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ok. I hear ya. Thanks!

Comment: well put, @RocketHazmat, please post this as an answer.

Comment: If you can use the data, it's a security breach: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to see the JSON data in your debug tools, but you can't access it in your code unless it's in the right format.  JSONP works by adding a `<script>` tag to your page's `<head>`. That's how it bypasses the same-origin policy. JSONP is not JSON, it's just a JavaScript file; a function call. If it's not wrapped in a function call, it's not JSONP, and cannot be used as such.

The server you are using needs to support JSONP for you to use their data cross-domain.  See if they support CORS, if they do then you can try that.

If the server does not support any cross-domain technologies (JSONP or CORS), then your only other option is to make a script on your own webhost to act as a proxy.  Make an AJAX call to your server and have it relay back the JSON data.